# H2O Steam deploy can't connect to Prediction Service Builder

Tags: h2o

I am trying to use `h2o steam` (running on localhost) to deploy a model. After importing the model from `h2o flow`, clicking the `"deploy model"` option in the `"models"` section of the project, filling out the resulting dialog box, and clicking the "deploy" button, the following messages are displayed:

[image]

At first I thought that it was because maybe I needed to start up the service builder on my own, so I started it up following the docs [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/steam/latest-stable/steam-docs/prediction_service.html#build-and-run-the-builder-service), but still got the same error. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking [here](https://www.grc.com/port_8080.htm), it seems like I would need to "override" some kind of default browser restriction for accessing localhost:8080 (which is what I assume `steam` is trying to do to launch the service builder (I don't know much about networking related stuff)). I got around this by launching `steam` with the command:

```
$ ./steam serve master --prediction-service-host=localhost --prediction-service-port-range=12345:22345
```

where the ports are some arbitrary range between (1025, 65535) which I got by word-searching the a page of the `steam` source [code](https://github.com/h2oai/steam/blob/master/cli2/local.go) (line 182 as of the date of this posting).

Doing this lets me deploy the models through the `steam` dialog without any error messages. Again, I don't know much about networking related stuff, so if anyone has a better way to solve this problem (ie. allow access of localhost:8080) please post or comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure jetty HTTP server is running locally by executing the following in your shell:
`java -jar var/master/assets/jetty-runner.jar var/master/assets/ROOT.war`